# Count and Order By

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, sql-order-by

I have a table called MaintenanceRequests and it lists the Building #, Letter, ReqeustDate, Description, Resolution, CompletedDate and MaterialsUsed

I want to be able to count the number of maintenance requests per building. So if 1A had 10 requests and 1B had 3,building 1 has 13 total requests. Then I would like to just show the top 3.

What I have is this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Building, Count(Letter) AS NumberofRequests
FROM MaintenanceRequests
GROUP BY Building
ORDER BY NumberofRequests DESC;
```

However when I go to run the query it asks me for the parameter for NumberofRequests.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by the aggregate directly instead of by its alias

```
SELECT TOP 3 Building, Count(Letter) AS NumberofRequests
FROM MaintenanceRequests
GROUP BY Building
ORDER BY Count(Letter) DESC;
```